# cascade="all" or cascade="save-update"? NHibernate one-to-many won't update

Tags: nhibernate, updates, cascade, nhibernate-cascade

> **Problem encountered**

When I create a transient instance with a children collection, everything gets persisted.

Aside, if I update an instance of one of the children object, it doesn't get updated when I save the parent object.

I'm actually using `cascade="all"`

> **`Problem reproduction`**

The problem occurs when I have loaded all of my Customer occurences, and I change an invoice, though I always use the same `ISession`.

```
var repository = new CustomerRepository(session);
var customers = repository.GetAll();
var customer = customers.Where(c => c.Name == "Stack Overflow").FirstOrDefault();           
customer.Invoices
    .Where(i => i.Number == "1234")
    .Approve(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);    
repository.Save(customer);
```

Step by step debugging clearly shows the `repository.Save()` method being executed, and the changes won't show inte the underlying database.

*An update directly against the database table is possible, so no contraint causing the update to fail on the database-side.*

Herewith some code in case it might help.

> **`Customer.hbm.xml`**

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" 
                   namespace="MyProject.Model" 
                   assembly="MyProject">
    <class name="Customer" table="AC_CUST" schema="AC">
      <id name="Id" column="AC_CUST_ID" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0">
        <generator class="sequence-identity">
          <param name="sequence">AC_CUST_ID_SEQ</param>
          <param name="schema">AC</param>
        </generator>
      </id>
      <property name="Name" column="AC_CUST_NAME" type="String" 
                not-null="true" />
      <property name="PhoneNumber" column="AC_CUST_PHNUM" type="Int64" 
                not-null="true" />
      <bag name="Invoices" table="ESO_RAPP_ACCES_INFO_DSQ" schema="AC" 
           fetch="join" lazy="true" inverse="true" cascade="all">
        <key column="AC_CUST_ID" foreign-key="AC_CUST_INV_FK" />
        <one-to-many class="Invoice" />
      </bag>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

> **`Customer`**

```
public class Customer {
    public Customer() { Invoices = new List<Invoice>(); }

    public virtual int Id { get; proected set; }
    public virtual IList<Invoice> Invoices { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

> **`Invoice.hbm.xml`**

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" 
                   namespace="MyProject.Model" 
                   assembly="MyProject">
    <class name="Invoice" table="AC_INV" schema="AC">
      <id name="Id" column="AC_INV_ID" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0">
        <generator class="sequence-identity">
          <param name="sequence">AC_INV_ID_SEQ</param>
          <param name="schema">AC</param>
        </generator>
      </id>
      <property name="Approved" column="AC_INV_APPRD" type="DateTime" 
                not-null="false" />
      <property name="Approver" column="AC_INV_APPRR" type="String" length="15" 
                not-null="false" />
      <property name="Number" column="AC_INV_NUMBR" type="String" length="15" 
                not-null="true" />
      <property name="Produced" column="AC_INV_PROD" type="DateTime" 
                not-null="false" />
      <many-to-one class="Customer" column="AC_CUST_ID" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

> **`Invoice`**

```
public class Invoice {
    public Invoice() { 
        Items = new List<Item>(); 
        Produced = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public virtual DateTime? Approved { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Approver { get; protected set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual int Id { get; proected set; }
    public virtual string Number { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? Produced { get; set; }

    public virtual void Approve(string approver) {
        Approved = DateTime.Now;
        Approver = approver;
    }

    public virtual void Reject() { Produced = null; }
}
```

> **`CustomerRepository`**

```
public class CustomerRepository {
    public CustomerRepository(ISession session) { Session = session; }

    public ISession Session { get; protected set; }

    public Customer Save(Customer instance) {
        Session.SaveOrUpdate(instance);
        return Instance;
    }
}
```

> **Related articles**

- [**nHibernate one-to-many inserts but doesnt update**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732708/nhibernate-one-to-many-inserts-but-doesnt-update)
- [**NHibernate - code example for update**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536757/nhibernate-code-example-for-update)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is your `FlushMode` set to when you build the `SessionFactory`?

Comment: `ISession.FlushMode == FlushMode.Auto`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to `Flush()` your session!

NHibernate keeps track of all the changes along a session lifecycle which should only live for a form (Desktop) or a page (Web).

Because of the session is aware of all the changes, it doesn't necessarily commit the changes to the underlying database. Instead, it keeps a record of all the changes into a dictionary, then when it is flushed by calling `ISession.Flush()`, you actually demand the session to commit the changes for good.

So solution shall be:

```
repository.Save(customer);
session.Flush();
```

Or you may as well code a `Commit()` method within your repository which would `Flush()` the session upon a call.

```
repository.Save(customer);
repository.Commit();
```

And your repository would look like:

```
// Assuming you stock your session in the `Session` property.
public void Commit() { Session.Flush(); }
```

That's all!